# Is every variety an image of a smooth variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, smoothness

Let $X$ be a finite type scheme over a field $k$.

Is it true that there exists a surjective morphism $f : Y \rightarrow X$, where $Y$ is smooth over $k$?

In other words, is every such scheme a quotient of a smooth scheme over $k$?

Comment: Yes - see for instance de Jong's *Smoothness, semi-stability and alterations* ([Numdam link](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1996__83__51_0.pdf)).

Comment: Yes, this is a result of de Jong, Publ. Math. IHÉS 83 (1996), 51-93. You can assume moreover that $f$ is proper and generically finite ("alteration").

Comment: This is false unless the field is perfect, so assume that the field is perfect. The proof by de Jong gives a surjective morphism that is *proper*.  If you do not require the surjective morphism to be proper (which is not required in the original post), this is elementary: stratify your scheme by locally closed subsets that are smooth over the perfect field.

Comment: As stated, the question has an easy answer. If $X$ is reduced (and $k$ is perfect), there is a dense open $U_0\subseteq X$ which is smooth. Let $X_1 = X\setminus U_0$, with the reduced subscheme structure. This has smaller dimension and again there is a smooth dense open $U_1\subseteq X_1$. We continue this for $\dim X$ steps and take $Y = \coprod U_i$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the second half of Jason Starr's comment. If you want $Y$ irreducible, I guess that you can repeatedly apply the operation: (1) blow up the singular locus, (2) normalize, (3) take the smooth locus. At some step the smooth locus should surject onto $X$. E.g. in the case of an isolated singularity at $x$, the normalized blowup at $x$ cannot be singular everywhere on the exceptional divisor, so the smooth locus will surject onto $X$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably, you want to say that $X$ is reduced, since $Y$ will be reduced and any map from a reduced scheme lands in $X^{\mathrm{red}}$. Once you've said that, this follows from De Jong's alterations theorem, appearing in

- A.J. De Jong, *Smoothness, semi-stability and alterations*, Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS, Tome 83 (1996), pp. 51–93, doi:[10.1007/BF02698644](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02698644),
  [Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1996__83__51_0).

Comment: Yes, I do want to say that. :)

Comment: For the first question (asking for a surjective $f$) $X$ does not have to be reduced since $X^{\mathrm {red}}\to X$ is surjective. For the second question, we must define "quotient" but any reasonable definition would exclude a non-reduced $X$.

Comment: Fair point on the first question. I would have imagined "surjective" meant "scheme theoretic image is $X$", but of course that is not the only definition one could imagine.